# Spree template - deface conditional code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am trying to modify this view file: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/checkout/edit.html.erb

All I want to do is to modify a class twelve to ten in this line:

```
 <div class="columns <%= if @order.state != 'confirm' then 'alpha twelve' else 'alpha omega sixteen' end %>" data-hook="checkout_form_wrapper">
```

What would be the best way to do it? The only solution I can come up with is to use following deface script, but this does not seem to be the beautiful way:

```
<!-- replace '[data-hook="checkout_content"]' -->
<div class="row" data-hook="checkout_content">
<div class="columns <%= if @order.state != 'confirm' then 'alpha ten' else 'alpha omega sixteen' end %>" data-hook="checkout_form_wrapper">
  <%= form_for @order, :url => update_checkout_path(@order.state), :html => { :id => "checkout_form_#{@order.state}" } do |form| %>
    <% unless @order.email? %>
      <p class="field" style='clear: both'>
        <%= form.label :email %><br />
        <%= form.text_field :email %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <%= render @order.state, :form => form %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% if @order.state != 'confirm' %>
  <div id="checkout-summary" data-hook="checkout_summary_box" class="columns omega six">
    <%= render :partial => 'summary', :locals => { :order => @order } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is there any other way to achieve my goal? Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the set attributes property of deface to change the property of the class for that div.

From the deface docs:

> :set_attributes - Sets attributes on all elements that match the
>   supplied selector, replacing existing attribute value if present or
>   adding if not. Expects :attributes option to be passed

Also for a slightly different solution, you could try a CSS selector to set the width:

```
div.twelve[data-hook="checkout_form_wrapper"] {
  width: something_less_than_what_you_had_before
}
```

Comment: The only option I can consider would be the first one. However, I am not sure about the syntax, as the class I want to modify is applied conditionally.

Comment: There are some examples of the syntax in the specs for deface.  https://github.com/spree/deface/blob/master/spec/deface/actions/set_attributes_spec.rb